# why does a PostMessage to external app acts different from the keyboard

Tags: delphi, windows-7

I'm writing a delphi app (myApp) to input keyboard strokes to an external app (extApp).

When extApp launches in windows 7 and I press {tab}{tab}{down} i have the appropriate item in the list box selected. The down arrow selects the second item in the TListBox (WinSpy++ tells me it's a TListBox).

Why then does myApp using this code not have the same functionality as the keyboard? This code will select the TListBox (a result of {tab}{tab} and then NOT move the ListBox selection!

```
    procedure TfrmMain.run;
    begin
      setForegroundWindow(extApp);
      sendTab(extApp);
      sendTab(extApp);
      sendDown(extApp);
    end

    procedure TfrmMain.sendTab(h: HWND);
    begin
      PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
      PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP,   VK_TAB, 0);
    end;
    procedure TfrmMain.sendDown(h:HWND);
    begin
      PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0);
      PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP,   VK_DOWN  , 0);
    end;
```

Is there a different way I can send a down arrow key stroke to my external app that will mimic the physical keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried adding some small delays between the sendxxx commands?

Comment: Yeah. I've added a Sleep(500) between my PostMessages

Comment: You are not setting any of the appropriate state flags in the `lParam` parameter of the messages. At a minimum, you should be setting the bits for scan codes, previous key states, and transition states.

Comment: Allow me to suggest UI Automation

Comment: That may be worth looking into!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do so is using [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx). Something like this should get you started:

```
var
  Inputs: array of TInput;
  ScanCode: Word;
begin
  ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(VK_TAB, 0);

  SetLength(Inputs, 2);
  Inputs[0].iType := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_TAB;
  Inputs[0].ki.wScan := ScanCode;

  Inputs[1].iType := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := VK_TAB;
  Inputs[1].ki.wScan := ScanCode;
  Inputs[i].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  SendInput(2, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));
end;
```

Comment: The downside with this approach is that you lose the ability to target a specific window, like the original code was doing.

Comment: @Remy: True. The upside is that it actually sends the keys. :-)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Guess my solution was not the easy way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting any of the appropriate state flags in the lParam parameter of the messages. At a minimum, you should be setting the bits for scan codes, previous key states, and transition states, eg:

```
procedure TfrmMain.sendTab(h: HWND);
var
  ScanCode: UINT:
begin
  ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(VK_TAB, 0) shl 16;
  PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, ScanCode);
  Sleep(50);
  PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP,   VK_TAB, ScanCode or $C0000001);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.sendDown(h:HWND);
var
  ScanCode: UINT:
begin
  ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(VK_DOWN, 0) shl 16;
  PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, ScanCode);
  Sleep(50);
  PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP,   VK_DOWN, ScanCode or $C0000001);
end;
```

That being said, [you can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx), so use [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead, like Ken White suggested (though you lose the ability to direct the keyboard input to a specific window, it will always go to the foreground window - but then, so does real keyboard input).

Comment: Thanks Remy Looks like it was SendInput after all.